# How to change Zfcuser form error message?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zfcuser

I'm trying to change the validation message for zfcuser register form. I have try to change the message by using following code in bootstrap.php:

```
$filter->get('email')->setErrorMessage('Email address has been used', \ZfcUser\Validator\AbstractRecord::ERROR_RECORD_FOUND);
```

However, this line of code changes all my email invalid message but what I want to achieve is different validation messages for different errors.

For example:

```
Email exist => 'Email address has been used'
Invalid format => 'Email not valid'
Not input => 'Please input your email'
```

Anyone can share with me anyway to achieve that?

Comment: You need to [set the error message on the validator](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.validator.messages.html) rather than the form input. It would also make sense to do so when creating it (rather than after)

Comment: do you mean i can subclass the validator and set the error message myself?

Comment: You can hint to the [input filter when you create the form](https://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#hinting-to-the-input-filter), they all allow an `'options' = array()` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Maybe it's ugly, but it seems that it should work

```
$filter = $form->getInputFilter();
$validators = $filter->get('email')->getValidatorChain()->getValidators();
foreach ($validators as $validator) {
    if ($validator['instance'] instanceof \ZfcUser\Validator\AbstractRecord) {
        $validator['instance']->setOptions(array(
            'messageTemplates' => array(
                'recordFound' => 'Email address has been used',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```